# Jqgrid and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid and I have a problem with checkboxes.

I have a column in my database that returns `'S' --> true` and `'N'--> false`.

I've seen some examples on the Internet and I chose this way (thinking that was the correct one):

```
{name:'acc_web', index:'acc_web', width:60, editable:true, edittype:"checkbox", formatter:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"S:N"}},
```

However, this always checks as `true` the checkbox. Is anything wrong here? Furthermore, I have put it as `editable`, but I can't!

The entire code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ 
        url:'obtieneUsuarios.do', 
        datatype: "json", 
        colNames:['Acceso web','Primer apellido','Segundo apellido','Nombre','Login', 'Perfil'], 
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'acc_web', index:'acc_web', width:60, editable:true, edittype:"checkbox", formatter:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"S:N"}},               
            {name:'apellido1',index:'apellido1', width:200},
            {name:'apellido2',index:'apellido2', width:200},
            {name:'nombre',index:'nombre', width:160},               
            {name:'login',index:'login', width:100}, 
            {name:'perfil',index:'perfil', width:160}
        ], 
        width: 820,
        height: 200,
        rowNum:10, 
        rowList:[5,10,20], 
        pager: '#pager2', 
        sortname: 'apellido1', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "asc", 
        caption:"Listado de usuarios"
    }); 
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Finally I solved the problem:
>
> Checkbox in `jqgrid` recognizes only some attributes as `false,0,No,undefined` and some more. I only have to map my results to these ones. In this case: `'S' --> 1` and `'N' --> 0`. With this mapping, problems solved :)